# How do you translate the "n-deklination" in tn English?

Tags: german-to-english

I just got familiar with [**n-deklination**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKnHTjoz74Y).
However, I do not understand how do you translate the "**n-deklination**" when you are translating a sentence from German to English?

For example, how do you translate the two below sentences:

> Wir bitten den Experten um Hilfe.

and the next sentence:

> Wir bitten den Expert um Hilfe.

Comment: _Wir bitten den Expert um Hilfe._ is wrong. Where did you got that from?

Comment: if you think, it is wrong it would be more professional to explain why the second sentence is wrong in an answer.

Comment: Your quesiton would be clearer is you explain exactly, why you think that this translation would be correct. Just linking a video, and expect everyone to watch it in full length isn't very helpful to understand your thoughts.

Comment: @Jimmy: If you tell us how you arrive at a wrong sentence, we can hopefully directly spot and address the error in your rationale. This is more easy for us and also likely more helpful to you. The alternative is that we start from scratch and explain everything relevant in hope that we capture your misunderstanding.

Comment: It is encouraged to give a link to a source - and it is encouraged to cite the relevant part as sources might disappear. Additionally a video contains no text at all to use a find algorithm. So please add at least the relevant quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declension class does not affect meaning. *Mice* and *sheep* are plural forms just like *dogs*. The fact that one ends in *-s*, one has no ending and one has an umlaut doesn't enter into the meaning. The same goes for *den Experten* versus *den Fachmann* (*-en* versus no ending); they're just accusative singular forms.

Note that the ending is obligatory; *den Experte* is wrong (and *Expert* does not exist).